# Form Submission in Modal Window and Refresh Content of a Tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have 2 tabs: list.brands and add.brand:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.brands">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info" ng-controller="BrandsCtrl">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="searchBox">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><tags:label text="brandid"/></th>
                        <th><tags:label text="name"/></th>
                        <th><tags:label text="isactive"/></th>
                        <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="actionresult{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="brand in brands | filter:searchBox">
                            <td>{{brand.brandid}}</td>
                            <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{brand.isactive}}</td>

                            <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-ext-darkblue btn-ext-darkblue savestockbtn" ng-click="open(brand.brandid)"><tags:label text="edit"/></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-ext-darkblue btn-modal-trigger btn-ext-darkblue savestockbtn" href="/admin.brands/deleteConfirm?brandid={{brand.brandid}}" data-toggle="modal" ><tags:label text="delete"/></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </script>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="add.brand">
    <div class="row-fluid sortable">
        <div class="box span12">
            <div class="box-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action='/admin.brands/add' data-toggle="modalform" data-popup="modal" name="brandform">
                        <div class="section-heading"></div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="name"/> *</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="name" required/>
                                <span ng-show="brandform.name.$error.required"> Name is required. </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="isactive"/> </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="isactive" value="1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="section-heading"><tags:label text="logo"/></div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textarea2"></label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <template:file.upload dropzoneWidth="200px" dropzoneHeight="160px" maxFiles="1"></template:file.upload>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <a href="/admin.brands" class="btn btn-ext-darkblue"><tags:label text="close"/></a>
                            <button ng-disabled="brandform.name.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-ext-lightblue"><tags:label text="save"/></button>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </script>
```

I switch them with

```
<div class="content-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="content-name span4">
                        <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></i><tags:label text="brands"/></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8 button-group">
                        <jsp:include page="/admin/jsp/screens/help-button-inc.jsp"></jsp:include>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
             <div id="tabs" >
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs content-tab-header" id="content_tab_0">

                    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" ng-click="onClickTab(tab)"><a><i class="{{tab.cssClass}}"></i><tags:label text="{{tab.title}}"/></a></li>
                </ul>

             </div>
             <div id="mainView">
                <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
             </div>
```

At list, I can open a modal window that contains brand details by clicking edit button in list.brands. My modal window:

```
<div class="row-fluid sortable">
    <div class="box span12">
        <div class="box-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="brandform" action='/admin.brands/update' data-toggle="validate" method="post">
            <fields:form formName="brand.id.form"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="brandid" value="{{item.brandid}}"/>
            </fields:form> 
            <fields:form formName="brand.form">  
                <div class="section-heading"></div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="name"/> *</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                        <input name="name" value="{{item.name}}" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="isactive"/> </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.isactive" name="isactive" value="1"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </fields:form> 
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <a ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-ext-lightblue"><tags:label text="close"/></a>
                    <a ng-click="ok()" class="btn btn-ext-darkblue btn-disable-on-submit" ><tags:label text="save"/></a>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and my app is here:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("BrandsCtrl", function($scope, $http, $controller) {
      $http.get('/admin.brands/getJSONDataOfSearch').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.brands = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
      angular.extend(this, $controller("BrandCtrl", {$scope: $scope}));
    });

app.controller("BrandCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
    $scope.open = function (id) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '/admin.brands/edit',
            controller:gg,
            resolve: {
                item: function($http) {
                    return $http.get('/admin.brands/getJsonBrandAndEdit?brandid=' + id)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            return response.data;
                        });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

var gg = function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {
    $scope.item  =  item;
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.form.brandform.submit();
        $modalInstance.close();
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {

        $modalInstance.dismiss();
      };
}
app.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'list.brands',
            url: 'list.brands',
            cssClass: 'icon-th-list'
        }, {
            title: 'add.brand',
            url: 'add.brand',
            cssClass: 'icon-plus'
    }];
    $scope.currentTab = 'list.brands';
    $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
        $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
    }
    $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
        return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
    }
}]);

</script>
```

My questions is; how can I submit my edit form in modal to a target URL and refresh the list of brands.

Comment: I think you want to share `brands data` between your two controllers. Using a `service` would be a good idea rather than extending the scope as you are trying to do. As soon as the form is submitted, refresh the `brands data` in the same service and that will update the UI everywhere.

Comment: How can I submit the form ?

How can I use a ``service``  ?

Answer (score 0):

in angular, form has a in-built event called `ng-submit`. You can submit the form in either way via submit button or using enter key. on `ng-submit event`, you need to pass a `function` which must be written within your `controller`. in that controller you can do what ever you want to do. To use a service, go through the documentation.

Here I am attaching an working example of **Form Submit** with **Service** integrated in it (Just for your reference, I have added 2 different controllers which are sharing the same service):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/zvcx5z38/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you. Thanks

```
$scope.open = function (id) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: '/admin.brands/edit',
        controller:gg,
        resolve: {
            item: function($http) {
                return $http.get('/admin.brands/getJsonBrandAndEdit?brandid=' + id)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
            }
        }
    });
modalInstance.result.then(function (item) {
        //The function that load your data in this controller   
        LoadData();
        })
}
```